# grunt import less watch

Tags: gruntjs, less, watch

I have 3 less files declared as well :

main.less : contains the css structure

main1.less : contains only variables (color) for a chart + @import main.less

main2.less : contains only variables (color) for another chart + @import main.less

When I build grunt, 2 css files are generated : main1.css and main2.css.

I would say that so far, so good.

But when I change the main.less, main1.less and main2.less are not reloaded. I have to modify also main1.less or main2.less for taking account into the main.less modification in livereload

```
watch: {
  options: {
    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
  },
  less: {
    files: ['<%= pkg.contentRoot %>/less/**'],

    tasks: [
      'newer:copy:styles',
      'newer:less:development'
    ],
    options: {
      event: ['changed']
    }
  },
```

Indeed, as the main.less is imported into main1.less and main2.less, the refresh doesn't work

So if I change main.less, I have to modify also main1.less for taking account into the modification in livereload

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: resolved based on this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252203/grunt-import-less-watch

Comment: you posted a link to this topic